# A suitable $\sigma$-algebra for this probability distribution over $\mathbb N$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\Omega= \mathbb N\backslash \{0\}$. Let the function $S(A)$ be defined:
$$S(A)= \begin{cases}
\sum_{i\in A} \frac {1}{2^i}, &\text {if $A \ne \emptyset$ and the sum is defined.}\\
0, &\text {if $A=\emptyset$.}
\end {cases}$$

The probability distribution I'm interested in is: $\forall i\in \Omega:P(\{i\})=\frac {1}{2^i}$. Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ such that $S(A)$ is defined. I don't think $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. What is a $\sigma$-algebra that is commonly used for this distribution?

Comment: It is  the power set. Singletons are needed and $\Omega$ is countable so every subset of $\Omega$ has to be in the sigma algebra.

Comment: Just to clarify: It is the power set because every singleton is needed and $\sigma$-algebra are closed under countable unions. Is this right? So, what is the probability of a subset $A$ such that $S(A)$ is not defined?

Comment: @jshthng: that sum is always defined (even when $A$ is empty; an empty sum is zero).

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: for any $A \subseteq \mathbb N - \{0\}$, $\sum_{i\in A} \frac{1}{2^i}$ is always defined? I didn't know that. Can I have a proof of this?

Comment: It converges e.g. by limit comparison to the usual geometric series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i}$, although that's overkill; you can verify convergence quite directly.

Comment: Anyway, the distribution you're interested in is called the geometric distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: @jshthng, think of it this way: if $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, then either it is finite, in which case the sum should be interpreted as a sum of the finitely many associated terms, or it can be enumerated as a sequence $A = \{a_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  At least intuitively speaking, the sum $\sum_{i \in A} 2^{-i}$ had better be nothing other than the value of the infinite series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-a_{n}}$.  Indeed, assuming you have defined $\sum_{i \in A}$ appropriately, this is true.  The question is: do you have a definition for such a sum?

Answer (score 0):

The question was: "What is a σ-algebra that is commonly used for this distribution?"

The answer is: $2^{\Omega}$.

Probability spaces of such type a called "Discrete probability spaces".